# SQL like statement

Tags: c#, sql

here i have tried to select a data from db make use of like statement, but it has search with the 1st digit of my data. but i need to write the code, like search instead of first 3 digit of my data. can any one help me.

```
public void CC()
        {
            CCddl.Items.Clear();
            ListItem l = new ListItem();
            l.Text = "-Select-";
            CCddl.Items.Add(l);
            CCddl.SelectedIndex = 0;
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Componetcode from dbo.tbl_component where Sitecode like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%'", con);
            SqlDataReader dr1;
            dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr1.Read())
            {
                ListItem n = new ListItem();
                n.Text = dr1["Componetcode"].ToString().Trim();
                CCddl.Items.Add(n);
            }
            dr1.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I see see a SQL injection.

Comment: Might be relevant: [Exploits of a Mom](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want..

Comment: C# has no like operator unlike VB.NET, so your title is misleading. You should also not prefix the title with your main tag(C#).

Comment: might i add.. 'your code is not safe' is none of your convern - i see this annoying commenting on security when question is about string replacements (or whatever, not injection-related) in most SQL related questions online! Put a sock in it allready, any of you flamers started thinking 'very clear problem statement!' instead of 'man that code is so cryptic even subzero wouldnt get by - but whats the q again?'?

Comment: @mschr dude chill theyre trying to do him a favour by pointing out a flaw, when i ask questions i love when people point out flaws i missed, because it makes the code better :S that like you calling the police for a robberry and them helping you, then you getting stabbed infront of them and them saynig sorry cant help you you called me out for a robbery this is a stabbing. then leaving :S

Answer (score 1):

**you cannot operate the like on number you need to convert number to stirng by using cast or convert ...**

**EDIT**

you can also make use of substring function to skip frist three char or your data in column

```
 select * from (
    select column1,cast(column2 as varchar(30)) as column2  from tablename 
  ) d  where 
    substring(column2,4, LEN(column2) - 3 )  like '%textosearch%'
```

---

you need to write down

```
select * from tablename where column like '___textosearch%'
```

so your code will be

```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Componetcode from dbo.tbl_component
         where Sitecode like '___" + TextBox1.Text + "%'", con);
```

_ allows you to match on a single character in sql , so you need to write three "_" as i done in my code

**Also modify you code with sql parameter so taht it avoid SQL injection attack**

Comment: friend, actually now it was load the all data from db

Comment: @AravindSai - just removed fir % sign and try out i updated in my code might work for you ...

Comment: didn't get any changes friend

Comment: sure.. shall i post the screen shot

Comment: @AravindSai - you can also try out the substring fuction as i used in my edit....

Comment: @AravindSai - you cannot operate the like on number you need to convert number to stirng by using cast or convert ...which you can see in my edit...

Comment: @AravindSai - welcome...dont forget to mark answer as accepted......and upvote the answer...